# Unity: Interception (AOP) intercepting Properties? and also intercepting methods on a form (winform)?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, aop

i am very interested in finding out if its possible to intercept Properties as well as Methods? I found a great example and seems to support intercepting Methods, would it also be possible to intercept Properties and what about events??

I would like to write a AOP logging system for my app.

here is the example: http://codetheorist.com/2011/04/interception-made-easy/

I gave it a try and managed to get it to work on a class library,

what if i would like to get it to work on WinForms?  I need to also resolve the Form from the container, a form in reality is a class but i couldn't get it to work.

Anyone have any ideas, or has already done it?

I did notice Aurum which is framework on top of Unity but i think i would prefer to use the Unity extensions if at all possible.

**EDIT**

This is what i tried for my winforms.... but it didn't work, its in program.cs

```cs
var form = UnityContainer.Container.Resolve<frmMain>();

///Application.Run(new frmMain());  // OLD

Application.Run(form);  // new using the resolved from unity.. It resolves it and i registered it ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A property is just a method with some additional metadata, so if the property is virtual or part of an interface it can be intercepted - just like any other virtual method.

Comment: Ah ok, yes with the setters and getters, so assume the method doesn't need to be adapted to capture the properties...  Additional metadata?? do i need  to check for this?

Comment: Actually, since System.Windows.Forms.Form inherits from MarshalByRefObject, you can intercept anything if you use the TransparentProxyInterceptor, you're not limited to virtual or interface methods only.